# .net - identify whether a button has a class when clicked

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, class

I have an asp button which I am using in 2 different places (appending to a new place and adding a class using jquery under certain conditions).

I need to slightly alter the function that runs when this button is clicked depending on whether or not this button has a given class. Is this possible??

So something like this...

```
if myASPButton hasclass("xyz") then
...
end if
```

i'm using vb.net for what it's worth.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible, clicking a button causes a postback, the only information posted back is form data. Modifications to the HTML client-side wont be reflected severside.

You will need to make a hidden field and populate the value of the hidden field and use that for checking severside.